# libcURL POST multipart upload (with buffered image) returning HTTP 400

Tags: c++, opencv, libcurl

I'm sending a POST multipart to the Cloudinary API to upload an image I've captured and buffered using openCV. Cloudinary is giving me a HTTP 400. I've tested uploading the image with the chrome app `PostMan` and that works, so there must be an error in my POST request or something wrong about how I'm buffering my data.

Heres how they describe calls to the API:
http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#uploading_with_a_direct_call_to_the_api

I've been at this for days and any help would be greatly appreciated. Once this is figured out I will be submitting this code to Cloudinary so other users fiddling with C/C++ can easily upload to their platform without the pain I've gone through.

```
//Clone frame and encode into buffer as JPEG
cv::Mat hand_roi = frame.clone();
std::vector<unsigned char> imgBuffer; 
imencode(".jpg", hand_roi, imgBuffer);

//Buffer to String with pointer/length
std::string imgStrBuff = std::string(imgBuffer.begin(), imgBuffer.end());
char *imgBuffPtr = (char *)&imgStrBuff;
long imgBuffLength = static_cast<long>(imgStrBuff.size());

//Unix time in (s)
std::time_t t = std::time(0);
std::string unixTime = std::to_string(t);

//API_Secret:
std::string APISecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

//Create SHA1 signature required by cloudinary
std::string hashString = "timestamp=" + unixTime + APISecret;
std::string authSig = sha1(hashString);

//POST URL
std::string url = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/xxxxxxxxxxx/image/upload";

/*-----CURL SETUP-----*/
//Set headers as null
struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
struct curl_httppost *formpost = NULL;
struct curl_httppost *lastptr = NULL;

//Data type 
curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data");

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "api_key",
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "xxxAPIKeyxxx",
             CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "timestamp",
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, unixT.c_str(),
             CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "signature",
             CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, authSig.c_str(),
             CURLFORM_END);

curl_formadd(&formpost,
             &lastptr,
             CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file",
             CURLFORM_BUFFER, "random_img_name.jpg",
             CURLFORM_BUFFERPTR, imgBuffPtr,
             CURLFORM_BUFFERLENGTH, imgBuffLength,
             CURLFORM_END);

//init easy_curl
CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

if(!curl)
    return false;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

I've read basically all the libcurl documentation and I just can't figure out why these requests are being rejected.

Comment: There is no language "C/C++". Only the two **different** languages C and C++.

Comment: Use a packet sniffer, like Wireshark, to see what Chrome is actually posting, then compare that to what libcurl is posting. That will help you pinpoint what is wrong/missing in your libcurl calls.

Comment: No need for CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, libcurl will set the correct content-type itself when you use CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.

Comment: In addition to @RemyLebeau's comment, you can just use your browser's dev tools, both Chrome and Firefox have built-in tools that allow you to view the POST request it sent. Compare that with what your libcurl post sends. Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has several issues, I'm going to address them one by one, starting with the most critical one which causes the operation to actually fail.

#### 1) You are feeding CURL a garbage pointer as file buffer

The problem lies in this part:

```
std::string imgStrBuff = std::string(imgBuffer.begin(), imgBuffer.end());
char *imgBuffPtr = (char *)&imgStrBuff;
long imgBuffLength = static_cast<long>(imgStrBuff.size());
```

What this does: It fills the `imgBuffer` into a C++ string `imgStrBuff` and then **misinterprets the pointer to the string descriptor as pointer to the actual data** and stores it in `imgBuffPtr`. The (correct) length of the data is stored in `imgBuffLength`.

So, further down, you are asking CURL to read `imgBuffLength` bytes from the memory starting at address `imgBuffPtr`... and you are lucky your program didn't just crash, because it will now read the string descriptor and whatever junk is by chance located in memory right after it, instead of the actual data!

I guess what you actually wanted to do is `char *imgBuffPtr = imgStrBuff.c_str();`, but there is an even better way without any string in between:

```
char *imgBuffPtr = &imgBuffer[0];
long imgBuffLength = imgBuffer.size();
```

The standard requires a `std::vector` to store its data in continuous memory, so it is save to just use the pointer to its first element.

#### 2) You are calling `curl_global_init` not at the right time

`curl_global_init` should be called before any other CURL functions, but you need to call it only once. So in this specific code, it would have to go above the call to `curl_slist_append`, but actually you would need it only in your program's startup routine somewhere.

#### 3) You are not assigning the result of `curl_slist_append` to `headers`

This line does effectively nothing (except for creating a list and leaking it):

```
curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
```

This is because you have to assign its return value back to the variable `headers`, like this:

```
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: multipart/form-data");
```

#### 4) The `Content-Type` header is unnecessary

As already pointed out by commenter Daniel Stenberg, there is no need to set your content type as a header because `CURL_HTTPPOST` will do that for you already - it has to, actually, because it has to define a multipart boundary as well.

#### 5) You are leaking data structures

*The following only applies in case you don't have this already somewhere further down in your code:*

You are creating an easy session variable `curl`, a `curl_slist` `headers` (although this is made obsolete by #4) and a `curl_httppost` structure `formpost`.

After you are done, you have to free them again using the following code:

```
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
curl_formfree(formpost);
curl_slist_free_all(headers);
```

#### A little debugging help for the future

There are two things you should definitiely do the next time you encounter such a problem:

1. As suggested by commenter Remy Lebeau already, use a packet sniffer such as Wireshark or SmartSniff, or an analyzing proxy such as Fiddler, to see what is actually being sent or received. You might need to change the protocol to `http://` for this to work though (change it back afterwards!), because otherwise you will only see encrypted SSL data. This way you can understand what is really going over the line and where the problem might lie. You can then also compare two versions of the data, one which works (e.g. from command line or browser) and yours which doesn't work.
2. Check the actual response body coming back from the API. You will probably need `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);` so you get a body in the first place even when the status code is >=400, and a data write callback (check out [this example](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html)). Had you done this, you would have noticed that the error sent by the API was `{"error":{"message":"Invalid image file"}}` which would have given you a clue already.

Comment: Cheers, thanks so much. The explanation about the garbage pointer was itself worth the points. Learned a lot from your post. I am curious about what exactly a string descriptor is and why it it points to junk instead of the string data.

Comment: That's because it contains some more information, mainly how long the string is (since in a `std:string` you can also store stings which contain a null character, which would otherwise terminate pure C strings) and the capacity of the string buffer (since the Library will manage the memory a bit more intelligently and, for example allocate a bit more capacity at once to prevent having to reallocate it every time you append stuff).

Comment: If you are interested in digging into this: http://info.prelert.com/blog/cpp-stdstring-implementations

Comment: Thanks! I'm not, not interested in digging into this :)

Answer (score 2):

You have got it all messed brother. Here's the sample code, request you to refactor your code. The biggest problem is with `curl_global_init` which needs to be the very first and then the `curl_slist_append` should accept the new pointer.

Take this below example and start updating your code one by and one and should be all set

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  struct curl_httppost *formpost=NULL;
  struct curl_httppost *lastptr=NULL;
  struct curl_slist *headerlist=NULL;
  static const char buf[] = "Expect:";

  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* Fill in the file upload field */
  curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "sendfile",
               CURLFORM_FILE, "postit2.c",
               CURLFORM_END);

  /* Fill in the filename field */
  curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "filename",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "postit2.c",
               CURLFORM_END);


  /* Fill in the submit field too, even if this is rarely needed */
  curl_formadd(&formpost,
               &lastptr,
               CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "submit",
               CURLFORM_COPYCONTENTS, "send",
               CURLFORM_END);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  /* initalize custom header list (stating that Expect: 100-continue is not
     wanted */
  headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf);
  if(curl) {
    /* what URL that receives this POST */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/examplepost.cgi");
    if ( (argc == 2) && (!strcmp(argv[1], "noexpectheader")) )
      /* only disable 100-continue header if explicitly requested */
      curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, formpost);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    /* then cleanup the formpost chain */
    curl_formfree(formpost);
    /* free slist */
    curl_slist_free_all (headerlist);
  }
  return 0;
}
```